# Why is eglMakeCurrent() failing with EGL_BAD_MATCH?

Tags: android, c++, opengl-es

I am developing for Android using opengl/egl. My app requires a second context for loading textures from a second thread.

My code works fine on android 2.3, but when I try the code on a 4.0.3 android device or emulator, eglMakeCurrent() fails with EGL_BAD_MATCH.

The initialization of the second context and it's pixel buffer all works fine too, so I am not sure where to begin looking for this error.

This is the initialization code:

```
ANativeWindow *window = (ANativeWindow*)displaySurface;

EGLint dummy, format;

display = eglGetDisplay(EGL_DEFAULT_DISPLAY);

eglInitialize(display, 0, 0);

EGLint contextAttribs[] =
{
    EGL_CONTEXT_CLIENT_VERSION, 2, EGL_NONE
};

const EGLint configAttribs[] =
{
    EGL_SURFACE_TYPE, EGL_WINDOW_BIT,
    EGL_RENDERABLE_TYPE, EGL_OPENGL_ES2_BIT,
    EGL_BLUE_SIZE, 8,
    EGL_GREEN_SIZE, 8,
    EGL_RED_SIZE, 8,
    EGL_ALPHA_SIZE, 8,
    EGL_BUFFER_SIZE, 32,
    EGL_DEPTH_SIZE, 24,
    EGL_NONE
};

EGLint numConfigs;
EGLConfig config;

eglChooseConfig(display, configAttribs, &config, 1, &numConfigs);
eglGetConfigAttrib(display, config, EGL_NATIVE_VISUAL_ID, &format);
ANativeWindow_setBuffersGeometry(window, 0, 0, format);

surface = eglCreateWindowSurface(display, config, window, NULL);
if(surface == NULL)
    Trace("error creating window surface: " + GetEglError());

context = eglCreateContext(display, config, EGL_NO_CONTEXT, contextAttribs);
if(context == NULL)
    Trace("error creating main context: " + GetEglError());

const EGLint auxConfigAttribs[] =
{
    EGL_SURFACE_TYPE, EGL_PBUFFER_BIT,
    EGL_BLUE_SIZE, 8,
    EGL_GREEN_SIZE, 8,
    EGL_RED_SIZE, 8,
    EGL_ALPHA_SIZE, 8,
    EGL_DEPTH_SIZE, 0,
    EGL_STENCIL_SIZE, 0,
    EGL_NONE
};

EGLint pbufferAttribs[] =
{
    EGL_WIDTH, 1,
    EGL_HEIGHT, 1,
    EGL_TEXTURE_TARGET, EGL_NO_TEXTURE,
    EGL_TEXTURE_FORMAT, EGL_NO_TEXTURE,
    EGL_NONE
};

EGLint auxNumConfigs;
EGLConfig auxConfig;

eglChooseConfig(display, auxConfigAttribs, &auxConfig, 1, &auxNumConfigs);

auxSurface = eglCreatePbufferSurface(display, auxConfig, pbufferAttribs);
if(auxSurface == NULL)
    Trace("error creating pbuffer surface: " + GetEglError());

auxContext = eglCreateContext(display, auxConfig, context, contextAttribs);
if(auxSurface == NULL)
    Trace("error creating auxilliary context: " + GetEglError());

if(!eglMakeCurrent(display, surface, surface, context))
    Trace("could not make main context current: " + GetEglError());
```

On my Android 2.3 device(HTC Desire), the above initialization code works perfectly, and I can make the auxContext current, and load textures just fine.

BUT, on my android 4.0.3 device(Samsung Nexus S) and my Android 4.1 device (Galaxy Note 2) eglMakeCurrent() fails with EGL_BAD_MATCH after a successful initialization.

Does anyone know why I may be getting this error?

Comment: I noticed that I get EGL_BAD_MATCH when calling eglMakeCurrent from a Galaxy S2 sometimes. I believe I have narrowed the error conditions down to either a) creating the context on a different thread than it is made current, or b) making the context current on a second thread without ~freeing it from the first thread.

Comment: see the comments on the marked answer for solution

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ah, something I actually know something about. ;) [Having spent best part of 5 years working on various EGL implementations].

I'm pretty certain your `surface` is a different format to the actual display surface. I'm not sure exactly WHAT the difference would be, or what you need to change. EGL_DEPTH_SIZE perhaps? You could try enumerating the modes that are available and see if any look "likely". I know, it's a bit of a pain, but I've been there done that a few times in the past - with the difference that I could usually look through the EGL source code and figure out what I'd done wrong... ;)

Comment: The thing is, that makeCurrent() works fine for the main context on all phones, but not for the second/shared context on the other two phones. However, I found a post which also suggests something like what you are saying: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7523597/egl-bad-match-with-droid-droid-2 - I may be getting back a different configuration than what I am requesting for **surface**, but then creating the pixel buffer with the **requested** configuration instead of the **returned** configuration, which may be the cause of the batch match.

Comment: Yes, it's entirely possible to have a setup that works on one, two, five or 16 phones, but fails on one or two others. I was at one point responsible for testing the EGL driver for a particular model of hardware that used a different set of EGL configs than the other hardware we had available. So whenever a new test was introduced to the test suite, it would almost certainly break on my hardware, but work on all others. Then came the challenge of finding a "good compromise" for what worked on all platforms - or adding some code to deal with "If we have HW X, do this, else do that".

Comment: I tried enumerating all the configs, which led to two discoveries. First, almost every display config that supported EGL_WINDOW_BIT also supported EGL_PBUFFER_BIT, Which makes it completely pointless to create two separate configs. The second thing, was that eglChooseConfig doesn't seem work properly on all android devices/versions. This could be by design, as this happened on one of the emulators with no GPU support, but the config I was getting back didn't even meet the specs I fed in. So I wrote my own eglChooseConfig, and used the same config for both surfaces, and now everything works.

Comment: @bitwise could you please share the implementation of eglChooseConfig ?

Comment: @Jerikc I haven't used this code in a very long time, so I can't gauruntee it will suit your needs, let alone work, but here it is :) - http://ideone.com/etNRSW

Comment: @MatsPetersson can you please look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64087683/android-opengl-stuff-doesnt-work-on-some-devices-eglmakecurrent-failed-and-gld Similar issue, also with specific devices

Answer (score 6):

If your getting this error but not dealing with this surface or texture stuff, go to run and type .android
go to AVD and your current Emulator delete the user-date file usually on .img file, restart your emulator then test. This works for me, if it happens on while testing on your device, clear the data and restart your app. Cheers for those who find this helpful.

Comment: yes, I know, but for some reason this error happen to me and the accepted answer wasnt been helpful in my case. Then I solved it and post it here. So if someone else bump into these kind of error, they may find it useful.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure you have set `EGL_PBUFFER_BIT` for the `EGL_SURFACE_TYPE` in the attributes passed into `eglChooseConfig()` call. It's work for me