# Android OpenGL stuff doesn't work on some devices: eglMakeCurrent failed and glDrawArrays: glError 0x505

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

So I used very similar code from official Google Grafika Sample for video processing in my own app: https://github.com/google/grafika/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/android/grafika/ContinuousCaptureActivity.java

I tested that this code works fine on Nexus 5X, Xiaomi S2, Samsung S9 devices but Firebase Crashlytics reports errors (crashes) on other devices, and usually it's Huawei devices and Samsung of A series (A20, A30 and so on..) and some others

So I can't reproduce this error on my testing devices at all and I don't have devices which were reported by Firebase Crashlytics.

So can it be that this is device issue and not the code problem? It's from official Google sample so everything should be fine, but...

Has anyone run into the same problem? Any solutions for such devices?

So there are two errors were reported:

at this line (`GlUtil.checkGlError("glDrawArrays");`) https://github.com/google/grafika/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/android/grafika/gles/Texture2dProgram.java#L335

or at this line (`.makeCurrent();`) https://github.com/google/grafika/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/android/grafika/ContinuousCaptureActivity.java#L472

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To solve that just add this on your camera fragment :

```
override fun onPause() {
    super.onPause()
    cameraProvider?.unbindAll()
}
```

Don't forget to init camera into "onResume"

To debug an android application from crashlytics you have to use a service like LambdaTest which allows you to test your app on many real devices