# How to fix the 0x3009 (EGL_BAD_MATCH) issue while invoking eglCreatePbufferSurface?

Tags: android, egl, grafika

I use the `createOffscreenSurface` from [grafika](https://github.com/google/grafika):

```
/**
 * Creates an off-screen surface.
 */
public void createOffscreenSurface(int width, int height) {
    if (mEGLSurface != EGL14.EGL_NO_SURFACE) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("surface already created");
    }
    mEGLSurface = mEglCore.createOffscreenSurface(width, height);
    mWidth = width;
    mHeight = height;
}

/**
 * Creates an EGL surface associated with an offscreen buffer.
 */
public EGLSurface createOffscreenSurface(int width, int height) {
    int[] surfaceAttribs = {
            EGL14.EGL_WIDTH, width,
            EGL14.EGL_HEIGHT, height,
            EGL14.EGL_NONE
    };
    EGLSurface eglSurface = EGL14.eglCreatePbufferSurface(mEGLDisplay, mEGLConfig,
            surfaceAttribs, 0);
    checkEglError("eglCreatePbufferSurface");
    if (eglSurface == null) {
        throw new RuntimeException("surface was null");
    }
    return eglSurface;
}
```

It works fine on some devices, but doesn't on other devices. The error msg is:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: eglCreatePbufferSurface: EGL error: 0x3009
```

I also googled and got the following information:

1. > You need to setup the surface view with the appropriate pixel format for that phone, which is most likely PixelFormat.RGB565 ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7523597/egl-bad-match-with-droid-droid-2))
2. > I'm pretty certain your surface is a different format to the actual display surface. ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14062803/why-is-eglmakecurrent-failing-with-egl-bad-match))

However, i don't have ideas to fix it. Any suggestions ?

Comment: On the devices where it fails, do the Grafika activities that use pbuffers work? If so, what's different about the way you're using it?

Comment: Fails here: `EGLSurface eglSurface = EGL14.eglCreatePbufferSurface(mEGLDisplay, mEGLConfig,
            surfaceAttribs, 0);` I use the `OffscreenSurface` to do the screenshot.

Comment: See the solution here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40697339/error-egl-bad-match-in-android-studio-emulator/41948265#41948265](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40697339/error-egl-bad-match-in-android-studio-emulator/41948265#41948265)

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
new EglCore(EGL14.eglGetCurrentContext(), 0)
```

to replace

```
new EglCore(newSharedContext, EglCore.FLAG_RECORDABLE);
```

Comment: This does not work on 'Acer Liquid E3+' Are there any other Ideas?